# Modifying Cpanel account over SSH

Tags: linux, shell, ssh, cpanel, centos7

My Cpanel licence has expired and I need to enable shell access for account X , Can I do it over ssh as root? I'm able to create account , however I don't know hot to modify it. I was not able to find answer for this question.

Thank You.

Comment: Did I just got -1 for non payment ? Great :)

Comment: No, you probably got downvote because it's not a programming question. Maybe try on Unix & Linux, ServerFault, Webmasters, or SuperUser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change user shell through command line using " usermod " command

```
usermod -s /bin/bash USERNAME
```

You can check /etc/passwd file to verify user shell.